# Building TFS projects for a sample test plan?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

What I want to do is create a sample project and use it as a new build for learning MTM (Microsoft Test Manager).I am going through this video

http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/software-testing-with-visual-studio-2012-exam-70-497-jump-start#fbid=SxABT5LX4lV

and have hit a brick wall at 34.00 minutes as he uses a new build for a project, I am having trouble creating a new build , I get the following error

TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \TestPlan\Buildone: 
Exception Message: The process parameter BuildSettings is required but no value was set. A value must be set on the definition or when the build is queued (Category: #100 Required, Display Name: Items to Build). (type ArgumentException)
Exception Data Dictionary:
MS.TF.Diagnostics.Logged = True

I dont know if I need to do choose a build , all I want to do is give an overview of MTM (Microsoft Test Manager) and a sample test such as 'Users can logon to system'.

Comment: follow the [link](http://www.edsquared.com/2010/06/18/Deploying+Process+Template+Changes+Using+TFS+2010+Build.aspx) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In general, in order to run a test using *MTM* you need a build definition which builds the solution containing your test implementation and reference the drop location of the build in test plan then.

According to the error message you did not specify what solution has to be built in your build definition.

Are you familiar with creating a build definition?
If not there is a lot of articles on MSDN (here is one of them [Create a Build Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181716.aspx)).

Comment: I wouldnt say I am familar but I had a go , I get an error the process tab that I dont really understand.

Comment: Could you please provide more information about the build definition you have the problem with? Since you can not expect the guys which want to help watch the video first ;-)

Comment: The problem is on the process tab in the build definition.in the Items to Build section, the error says the solution wasn't found.

Comment: Please provide more information about the build definition. Just post screenshots from each tab of it so we could see all settings you done.

Comment: To solve the issue I created a new project in my TFS account, started from scratch and then mapped the file up to my project